# SharePoint 2010 - Unable to display Web Part, but appears correctly after browser refresh

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, list-view-web-part

We have a SharePoint 2010 Web Part page containing 4 XSLT List View Web Parts that utilize the same list. When the page is first visited, one of the Web Parts does not display, while the other 3 Web Parts work perfectly. The error given is:

Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator.
Correlation ID:d1e4594a-c87a-49a8-ba3c-610bfa18e4ba

After refreshing the browser or waiting for the Web Part to automatically refresh, the page loads correctly.

1) I can consistently recreate the error by making a change to the Web Part format like adding or removing the Manual Refresh Button.

2) If I reduce the columns the Web Part loads correctly. Currently, I have 22 displayed columns and depending on which columns are display it will work correctly with between 15 to 20 columns displayed.

3) The Web Part utilizes some minor conditional formatting like outlining cells based on date comparisons (# of days between today and when another date). It also outlines cells depending upon the contents of the cell and changes word color based upon text. So it's all pretty simple stuff.

4) We can't seem to find any correlation ID error message in the error logs besides:

09/27/2011 15:10:56.56 w3wp.exe (0x09CC) 0x0F50 SharePoint Foundation Logging Correlation Data xmnv Medium Name=Request (POST:http://this-is-the-address-of-the-page-giving-the-error) 4299ff73-e544-42bd-adff-e5fc872b21f8

Any ideas on what might be the cause or how best to troubleshoot this? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to narrow it down, can you try to create a separate page with that single webpart and let us know results ? Also the check the threshold limit and rowlimit of the CAMl query?

Comment: I am also facing same issue in production environment

Answer (score 1):

I find this article from MS http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2639184

Comment: Hi @Lac-Phan and welcome to our forum. Please dont just post a url to another site. Use a few lines to explain what kind of solution we might find there, and then link to the post. External urls tend to be short lived, and we plan to stay around for a while ;-)